# Flag in pending status

Tags: support, flags

I have been working on some flags in the past few days.

On some flags I have made, I get the status of **Pending**. I understand that this happened because I flagged these posts as low quality.
Can someone please explain how long will it take for this flag to be accepted or rejected?

Comment: How long is a piece of string? It will sit in the Low Quality Posts review queue until it has enough votes one way or the other. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Comment: I think VLQ may also go feed into triage.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you flag a post either a review task is created or your flag disappears in the moderator queue.

When the reviewers handle the queue they process the review task and once it is completed your flag will be marked helpful, disputed or declined. It takes multiple reviewers to complete a task so it might take a couple of hours up to days before the task get completed.

If your flag went into the moderator queue you basically have to wait until your flag gets sorted / filtered by a moderator in such a way that your flag popups on top. With the given stream of new flags that can be a bit of challenge but your flag will be processed, no matter what.

In rare cases where a flag is pending for months I might bring it up in chat if I run into a moderator.